# Apply try catch in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I tried using the try-catch block statement of SQL but it is giving an error in hive.
I looked out for documentation too but to no avail.
So how can I apply try-catch statement blocks in a hive script??

Syntax i tried

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
[ ; ]
```

taken from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: This is a `T-SQL` format which works only on `SQL Server`. `Hive SQL` documentation can be found here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual

Comment: Yea I know that,I hoped it would be same since hive follows SQL and since I couldnt find this in the documentation.Any idea how is it done?

Comment: Hive's Procdural Language supports exceptions: http://www.hplsql.org/exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HiveQL [does not support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) the `try catch` construct.